# Implementing ESSBASE script in Excel smart view

Tags: excel, essbase

I have a script which looks like this

```
           fix ("A",@relative("B",0),@relative("C",0))
                            "GP" = @Parentval(Product,"GP") * "V";
           endfix
```

I am trying to understand and analyze how this script is working in Excel using smart view.

What I am trying to do is maybe make a pivot with  "A", @relative("B",0), and @relative("C",0) by manually selecting those 3 from member selection.
Then I want to @Parentval(Product,"GP") and "V" then compare the result of the multiplication to "GP".

Is there a way to list the members that come up with @Parentval(Product,"GP") in excel using smart view?
Is there is a way to list the members that come up with commands like @Decendents() etc.?

Comment: Do you mean that your FIX script is a calculation script inside of Essbase?

Comment: yes the scripts that I gave is a part of a bigger script which is used inside Essbase. I am trying to understand the computation in excel. I have smartview. My objective is to analyze and learn how Essbase commands like  @Parentval() etc. and the other computations are working.

Comment: Understood. So the first thing you need to know is that the calculation script you posted above is something that is run on the cube and affects data in the cube. Smart View simply retrieves data from the cube. Changing the calc script doesn't affect what you see in Excel/Smart View -- you have to *run* the script to make it do something to the cube. So it's not really a matter of the script working inside of Excel. You might want to look into member formulas in the outline, as those will affect what you see in Excel directly.